# Trying to implement Swipe into existing code. Getting Incompatible types in getSupportFragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Error: Incompatible types. **Found: 'com.example.MyPagerAdapter', required: 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter'**

I am trying to implement swipe to switch between fragments as well as i have a menu icon which opens a list of options. The list menu part works great. However, when i am trying to connect MainActivity to MyPagerAdapter i am getting the error mentioned above. Since the code is rather lengthy i will give the relative parts. If i need to complete it with more code i will, of course, do so.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/** Swipe **/
FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    /** Swipe **/
    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); /** Incompatible types  **/

    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vpPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

MyPagerAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
```

Comment: obviously FragmentStatePagerAdapter and MyPagerAdapter are not derived FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the declaration, replace

```
FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
```

with:

```
MyPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
```